# How do I trim a .fits image and keep world coordinates for plotting in astropy Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, astronomy, astropy

This issue has been plaguing me for some time. I'm trying to handle some large amount of data that is in the form of a .fits file (on the order of 11000x9000 pixels). What I need to do is create a 'zoomed in' RA/Dec coordinate plot (ideally using astropy.wcs) for many objects on the sky with contours from one fits file, and greyscale (or heatmap from another).

My problem is that whenever I slice the data from the image (to my region of interest) I lose the association with the sky coordinates. This means that the sliced image isn't in the correct location.

I've adapted an example from [the astropy docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/) to save you the pain of my data. (*Note: I want the contours to cover more area than the image, whatever the solution is for this should work on both data*)

[image: The 'image' in the RH plot should be centered!]

Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import download_file
import numpy as np

fits_file = 'http://data.astropy.org/tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits'
image_file = download_file(fits_file, cache=True)
hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
wmap = WCS(hdu.header)
data = hdu.data

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection=wmap)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection=wmap)
# Scale input image
bottom, top = 0., 12000.
data = (((top - bottom) * (data - data.min())) / (data.max() - data.min())) + bottom


'''First plot'''
ax1.imshow(data, origin='lower', cmap='gist_heat_r')

# Now plot contours
xcont = np.arange(np.size(data, axis=1))
ycont = np.arange(np.size(data, axis=0))
colors = ['forestgreen','green', 'limegreen']
levels = [2000., 7000., 11800.]

ax1.contour(xcont, ycont, data, colors=colors, levels=levels, linewidths=0.5, smooth=16)
ax1.set_xlabel('RA')
ax1.set_ylabel('Dec')
ax1.set_title('Full image')

''' Second plot ''' 
datacut = data[250:650, 250:650]
ax2.imshow(datacut, origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
ax2.contour(xcont, ycont, data, colors=colors, levels=levels, linewidths=0.5, smooth=16)

ax2.set_xlabel('RA')
ax2.set_ylabel('')
ax2.set_title('Sliced image')
plt.show()
```

I tried using the WCS coords of my sliced chunk to fix this, but I'm not sure if I can pass it in anywhere!

```
pixcoords = wcs.wcs_pix2world(zip(*[range(250,650),range(250,650)]),1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The good news is: You can simply slice your `astropy.WCS` as well which makes your task relativly trivial:

```
...

wmapcut = wmap[250:650, 250:650] # sliced here
datacut = data[250:650, 250:650]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection=wmapcut) # use sliced wcs as projection
ax2.imshow(datacut, origin='lower', cmap='gist_heat_r')
# contour has to be sliced as well
ax2.contour(np.arange(datacut.shape[0]), np.arange(datacut.shape[1]), datacut, 
            colors=colors, levels=levels, linewidths=0.5, smooth=16)
...
```

[image]

If your files have different WCS you might need to do some reprojection (see for example [reproject](http://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

Comment: This is an excellent concise answer (using `.shape[0]` is super tidy!). Thank you for pointing out reproject, I didn't know it existed and I will definitely need it! One more thing; I'm trying to scatter a point on top of this and the axes coordinates don't appear to be mapped in degrees. For example plotting `ax1.scatter(85.33, -2.5)` should appear at (85 20' , -2 30') but it's a fair way off.

Comment: [`pywcsgrid2`](http://leejjoon.github.io/pywcsgrid2/) also has lots of good reprojection capabilities, and I find it a little more flexible than `astropy.WCS`, at the cost of a steeper learning curve. It can also overplot reasonably well.

Comment: @FriskyGrub To overlay scatter plots check out this example: https://wcsaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overlays.html#world-coordinates. If you have any trouble afterwards just ask another question (it's easier to deal with one problem per question). In short you need to apply a ``transform`` **or** specify the coordinates in pixel-coordinates.